# Where to find a 14.4 mm long and 16.9 mm wide hub cone?

Tags: hub, rims, replacement, bearings, cones

I was servicing my bike's ball bearings in my wheels when I noticed that the rear hub cones need to be replaced, as they are heavily wearing down. I looked online for replacement hubs but none fit the dimensions I need, maybe because the rim I have is an Alex Rims TD 24. As per the title, the cone hub is 14.4 mm long and 16.9 mm in diameter. Anybody have any products that would fit my needs? I assume once the product is found, finding the other side (the one on the cassette's side) would just be a matter of getting the same size but for the other side.

Comment: The rim has little bearing on the hub.   Do note that the cones may not be identical between sides - often the drive side is longer.   Take the old axle and cones into your LBS and ask for "one just like this, but not worn out please"  and pick up new ball bearings while you're there.

Comment: Ok I'll look into that after the holiday!! Thanks!!

Comment: Take the wheel in, as the LBS will look up distributor catalogues keyed off make and model of hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you visit your local bike shops, there is a slim chance to fund a replacement. On the other hand, the most reliable and time-efficient solution is to replace the whole axle. In my region, the options are an Weldette unit for about 7.5 EUR or a M-Wave axle for about 2.5 EUR. Do ask around.

[image]